# C# Index Search Like AVA Find

Tags: .net

You may be known about AVA Find, it first indexe the entire hard-disk, then you can search a file very fast, can find a file very fast (within a second even in a low end SPU). If do the same using SQL server, First index the file names in an sql server db , then search, it will take a long time. How can we create one like AVA Find in C# or dot net

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about avafind or if this is what you are looking for, but theres always Lucene.Net, an opensource .net search engine:
http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/